# Numpy: is there a way to provide a *name* to a location in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a **3 x 3 Numpy** array:

```
X =  np.array([[  0.,   2.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  4., 22.,   0.]])
```

Where each location within array X corresponds to some relationship between the following variables:

```
[  a & a,   a & b,   a & c]
[  b & a,   b & b,   b & c]
[  c & a,   c & b,   c & c]
```

So in the example array **X**, the number 2 corresponds to data that describes something about the relationship between variables **a** and **b**.

Now, say if I want to run a condition on X like so:

**X > 3**, which generates the following:

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

How do I then determine which variables in my **a, b and c** variable universe the **True** values correspond to? We know it is **c & a** and **c & b** but how do I pull this information out?

I thought maybe there is a way to assign names to fixed locations in a **Numpy** array?

I can do what I want as follows:

```
y =  np.array([[  'a',   'a',  'a'],
         [  'b',   'b',  'b'],
         [  'c',  'c', 'c']])

z =  np.array([[  'a',   'b',  'c'],
         [  'a',   'b',  'c'],
         [  'a',  'b', 'c']])

y[x>3]

array(['c', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
```

And:

```
z[x>3]

array(['a', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```

And then I can group the first index values in the results above to get **c & a** followed by the second index values to get **c & b**.

I'm not very experienced with the **Numpy** ecosystem so its unclear to me whether there is a better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: have you tried [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Comment: I know I can do this in pandas but my actual data set r several 2500 x 2500 arrays so 6 million records. Pandas likely not the best place to do this work given the data size and run time involved.

Comment: I just tried pandas with 10k by 10k and it's fine... generating the random data  that size via numpy takes ~2 seconds, pandas takes ~5 milliseconds to turn it into a data frame

Comment: Pandas is basically a fancy numpy wrapper. Overhead of Pandas over Numpy is negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use just one single index and then index away with `np.where`:

```
labels = np.array(['a','b','c'])

idx = np.array(np.where(X>3)).T
labels[idx]
```

Output:

```
array([['c', 'a'],
       ['c', 'b']], dtype='<U1')
```